# How to make responsive background with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write some text on div with background image , i make this code but it is not responsive . How to make the image and text responsive

HTML :

```
 <div class="h-100" id="background">
    <div class="container pt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h2 class="text-danger">WEBO DESIGN</h2>
<h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum dicta aliquam assumenda dolores adipisci! Quae reprehenderit quisquam fuga necessitatibus exercitationem ipsa consequatur enim itaque quam commodi unde, voluptas assumenda porro id qui voluptatem nobis atque. Aliquam autem perferendis maiores, est deserunt fuga quaerat, quibusdam et eos numquam nam, repellat obcaecati!</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
#background {
  background-image: url("../imgs/header.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the result i got : 
I want to fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vc8W.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38W4b.png)

Comment: Make the screenshot of your error and attach here. because your code is working fine.

Comment: How do you want it to behave, for you what do you mena with responsive in this case? What do you have tried?

Comment: On small screens the image disappears

Comment: I have added two images of what i get

Comment: Check the question again

Comment: do you want the image to be responsive, the text to be responsive, the container to be responsive... Please tell exactly what you want your result to be

Comment: The image and text to be responsive

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following. `outer` represents your size. Change it an the text and image will change. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

```css
#background {
      background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8f55e8c4bacf465accdc786b9ec1b392?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
#outer {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">

<div class="h-100" id="background">
        <div class="container pt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <h2 class="text-danger">WEBO DESIGN</h2>
    <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum dicta aliquam assumenda dolores adipisci! Quae reprehenderit quisquam fuga necessitatibus exercitationem ipsa consequatur enim itaque quam commodi unde, voluptas assumenda porro id qui voluptatem nobis atque. Aliquam autem perferendis maiores, est deserunt fuga quaerat, quibusdam et eos numquam nam, repellat obcaecati!</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be hidden . I want it to be responsive

Comment: You wrote _On small screens the image disappears_?

Comment: This is my problem that i want to fix

Comment: It doesn't fill the full width of the screen

Comment: and it still disapear

Comment: Yeah, otherwise it would distorted. If you can ignore that you can set `background-size: 100% 100%;`